# Updating text in a specific class div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, haml

In my application I make use of jquery to add a product to the shopping cart. This part works, but now I want to refresh some divs to show updated information after a product is added to the shopping cart.

first some code:
this is how the products are showed to the user

```
- @products.each do |product|
    .product
      .photo
        - x = 0
        - @product_attachments.each do |attachment|
          -if product.id == attachment.product_id && x == 0
            = image_tag attachment.image_url(:thumb)
            - x = 1
      .product_information
        .product_name
          %h3
            = product.name
        .product_price
          %h2
            = number_to_currency(product.price, :unit => "€", :separator => ",", :delimiter => ' ')
        %h4
          Categorie: #{product.category.title}
        %p.description
          =product.description
        %br/
        .stock
          Op vooraad: #{product.stock}
        .product_options
          = link_to 'meer informatie', product, class: 'show_product_link'
        = link_to orders_path(:product => product.id), :method => :post, :class=>'addToCart', :data => { :product_id => product.id} do
          .add_to_cart
            Toevoegen aan winkelmand
        - if user_signed_in? && current_user.admin?
          \#{link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(product)} |
          \#{link_to 'Destroy', product, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }}
```

when you click the link to add something to the cart, this jquery executes:

```
function refresh_information(data){
  //reloading the cart div to show the updated price
  $( ".cart" ).load(location.href + " .ajaxload");
  //reloading the stock div to show the updated stock
  $( ".stock" ).html( "Op vooraad:" +data.stock );
  console.log(data);
}

jQuery(function(){
  //listen for click on a class because this link is created dynamically
  $(".addToCart").click(function() {
    //put $(this) to select the data from the link that's actually clicked
    var product = $(this).data( "productId" );
    //ajax request to controller action to add product to cart
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/orders",
      data: { product: {id: product} },
      success:function(data) {
        //refresh some div's information
        refresh_information(data);
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

alright, now everything works fine until I want to refresh the stock div. It shows the right stock at the product you add to the cart, but it refreshes all the stock divs also those of the other products; to the stock of the product you put in your cart.

Now I know you can use `$.(this)`, I actually do this for getting the right product id. But the stock div is outside `$.(this)`, so that isn't working as far as I know.

Anybody knows a (pretty easy) solution to refresh only the stock div of the product added to the cart?

Thanks!

Comment: does it log the data to your console? Maybe try targeting the element you want to update using an id

Comment: Yes the data is logged, it also refreshes the divs. All the `.stock` divs, and it only needs to refresh the `.stock` div of the product added to the cart. I thought about using ID's but then I would have to use the product_id for the div id. Not sure if this is possible?

Comment: try either .sibling or .parent depending on how your htmls laid out see http://jsfiddle.net/kurtrohlandt/2b1fn2dk/. You would need to use javascripts this to identify the div

Comment: Thank you! this is going into the direction how I have it. But it actually is somewhat different. Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xjcajzvk/ I've added the divs that needs to be updated. (tried this too: `$(this).parent(".product").siblings(".stock").css( "background-color", "red" );`

Comment: here we go $("button.addtocart").click(function(){
$(this).siblings(".stock").css( "background-color", "red" );
}); the div is a sibling so .parent has no place in the equation. lets me know if i can post this as an answer

Comment: No, the `.stock` div isn't actually a sibling of the `.add_to_cart`, however they're both siblings of the `.product` div. It would work if the `$(this)` was the `.product` but that's not the case. I'm not too familiar with parents and siblings in jquery so I'm not entirely sure if what I say above is true. EDIT: In the fiddle it works with your last code, in my application not.. let me experiment some more.

Comment: weird you sure your html is right in the fiddle? check this https://jsfiddle.net/kurtrohlandt/xjcajzvk/1/

Comment: Alright, I tried to access $(this) in another function, so there was no $(this) I figure. I modified it where $(this) is saved in a variable, now it's working! Thank you very much :). -- you can post it as an answer

Comment: Glad I could help. sometimes its easier to solve other peoples problems than your own. I get stumped with seemingly simple stuff all the time lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your add to cart button is inside a div element with a class you need to target that specific element instead of all elements with the class as a whole. Using Javascripts this to catch the element that triggered the event and using jquerys .parent or .sibling functions to target the div should work.

```js
$("button.addtocart").click(function(){
$(this).siblings(".stock").css( "background-color", "red" );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product">
    <div class="stock">
        This div needs to be updated
    </div>
    a
    <button class="addtocart">add to cart</button>
</div>
<div class="product">
    <div class="stock">
        This div needs to be updated
    </div>
    b
    <button class="addtocart">add to cart</button>
</div>
<div class="product">
    <div class="stock">
        This div needs to be updated
    </div>
    c
    <button class="addtocart">add to cart</button>
</div>
```